# Driver for keyboard light not working

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-backlight

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ee/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y540-15irh/downloads

Is there a way to enable keyboard light, please let me know how I might install the driver from above.

https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15/p/88GMY501214

Thank you

Erika

Comment: What have you tried, and with which results? Are you trying to run a Windows driver in Linux? That's a FAIL.

Comment: Thanks, well I was hoping to do so. Btw, I am using a dual boot with FreeDOS, it does not work there either      (FreeDOS was the alternative that Legion was shipped with. I have tried the as I now understand, XP trick, adding drivers through ndisgtk, I am hoping to find out how to uninstall it... will be a new question I guess)